# How to view all connections through Router

Tags: networking, router, internet

So what I need to know is how find out who has been visiting what websites when **through the router**. It is similar to being able to **History** on browsers, but people can clear their history, or use **Incognito** mode. However, surely any data would be sent through the **router** so even if the person did clear their history or use incognito mode, you would be able to see what they had sent **through the router**, and **what the internet had sent back**.

Is there any way to view **all the connections** that the router manages, and ***store all the data*** that it **sends and receives** and put them into, for example, a **log file** so I could view **which computer** had viewed **what website** at **what time**?

The router is a BT Home Hub 3, which DD-WRT is not compatible with. I checked last month.

Comment: "through the router History Incognito router through the router what the internet had sent back all the connections store all the data sends and receives log file which computer what website what time" - Yup, much faster of a read. ;)

Comment: i'd say the downvote is because a) you have shown no research effort (What have you tried already? Have you checked to see if your router supports logging? etc.) b) you haven't included the make a model of your router. As-is, the short answer is: "Yes, some routers support this".  Does yours?  We can't know until you tell us the model.   But please, read the manual/feature set first, maybe try a 3rd party firmware like DD-WRT, etc. Try stuff, and tell us your results.

Comment: Agree with @techie007. Also, a consumer grade router is unlikely to provide the kind of information you are looking for without *WRT -  even then this requires understanding about ethereal/wireshark and netflow and the way the packets are structured.  What computer viewed what website at what time is a lot harder then it sounds (but is possible), because a single IP address can serve multiple websites - and sites like Google often do that, so the software needs to look inside the packet to extract the hosts header in the payload, which requires a lot more cpu then just looking at the header.

Comment: Updated - DD-WRT is not compatible with my router, and as far as I know the router can't do what I am asking